# plotting with args to have lines in the same plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I am looking to plot several values of a feature against time and I am using the `*args` argument to do so. What I am having is the several plots when enter two arguments or more in my function and I understand why this happens. However, I cannot figure out how to put all of them in the same plot. Here is what is my code to enlighten my intention.

Sample data:

```
year  city     population
2013  Ankara   xxxx
2013  London   xxxx
2013  Paris    xxx
....  .....    xxx
2014  Ankara   xxxx
2014  London   xxx
2014  Paris    xxxx
...   ....     ....
2015  Ankara   xxxx
....  ....     ....
```

When I do `df[df['city']=='Ankara'` I get a df with the population of Ankara and unique years. Now what I am trying to do is to get 2 or Three cities from this and plot them on the same plot.

```
 def city_over_time(*args):

     global df

     for city in args:
         df=df[df['city']==city]

         plt.plot(df.year, df.population)
         plt.tight_layout()
```

So when I do the following:

```
city_over_time('Manchester', 'Liverpool')
```

I get one plot for Manchester and another one for Liverpool below. But I want both in the same figure. just like if I was plotting the following:

```
 plt.plot(df[df.city=='Manchester']['year'], df[df.city=='Manchester']['population'])
 plt.plot(df[df.city=='Liverpool']['year'], df[df.city=='Liverpool']['population'])
```

Comment: Will you include a small sample of the DataFrame you are using to test out possible solutions?

Comment: There are some examples of what I think you are looking for in the [pandas docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.plot.line.html).

Comment: @HenryEcker done

Comment: @Alex not exactly but yes the aim is the same. However, I have one column on the example there is only one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`pivot`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html#pandas-dataframe-pivot) to get data in a more usable format, select cities as columns, then [`plot`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.plot.html#pandas-dataframe-plot):

```
def city_over_time(frame, *cities):
    plot_df = frame.pivot(index='year',
                          columns='cities',
                          values='population')[list(cities)]
    plot_df.plot(xticks=plot_df.index,
                 ylabel='Population')
    plt.tight_layout()
    plt.show()
```

Complete Working Example With Sample Data:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

np.random.seed(5)
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'year': np.repeat(np.arange(2013, 2016), 3),
    'cities': ['Ankara', 'London', 'Paris'] * 3,
    'population': np.random.randint(100_000, 200_000, size=9)
})

print(df)


def city_over_time(frame, *cities):
    plot_df = frame.pivot(index='year',
                          columns='cities',
                          values='population')[list(cities)]
    plot_df.plot(xticks=plot_df.index,
                 ylabel='Population')
    plt.tight_layout()
    plt.show()


city_over_time(df, 'London', 'Paris')
```

[image: London + Paris Population Over Time]

`df`:

```
   year  cities  population
0  2013  Ankara      135683
1  2013  London      118638
2  2013   Paris      120463
3  2014  Ankara      105520
4  2014  London      159465
5  2014   Paris      133800
6  2015  Ankara      133508
7  2015  London      181639
8  2015   Paris      134750
```

`plot_df` (`df` after `pivot` and filter on `cities`):

```
cities  London   Paris
year                  
2013    118638  120463
2014    159465  133800
2015    181639  134750
```